# two dimensional list takes huge amount of memory

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning

I have a 2d list which is created from lung CT image data and a label (the first item is a 3d array(image data) and the second item is a label(0 or 1)), I need this to data to train CNN model, the list is created using the code below:

```
def get3Dmatrix(ID_dist):

    print('preparing the 3d matrix')
    matrixlist=[]

    for Dist, xcoords, ycoords, zcoords, label in tqdm(ID_dist):
        # read the image
        imagearray,origin,spacing = load_itk_image(Dist)
        # resample in to 1mm*1mm*1mm
        imagearray = resample(imagearray,spacing,(1,1,1))

        # transfer world coordinates to voxel-coordinates, divide new spacing 1mm
        z = int(round((float(zcoords)-float(origin[0]))/1))
        y = int(round((float(ycoords)-float(origin[1]))/1))
        x = int(round((float(xcoords)-float(origin[2]))/1))

        # get the 3D array with shape 25*25*25           
        imagearray = imagearray[x-13:x+12,y-13:y+12,z-13:z+12]

        # or get the 3D array with shape 50*50*50 
        #imagearray = imagearray[x-25:x+25,y-25:y+25,z-25:z+25]

        matrixlist.append([imagearray,label])# 2d list consist of 3d array + label of all cases.
        return matrixlist



def main():
        start_time = time.time()
        # get ID_list from the csv and data dist.
        ID_list = getIDlist(candidates_V2_Dist, Data_Dist)# nested list - get file name with dist + x,y,z,class
        # Data_set[i][0] is the 3D array, Data_set[i][1] is the label
        Data_set = get3Dmatrix(ID_list) # 2d list consist of 3d array + label of all cases.
        print("Begin saving in numpy file")
        np.save(output_path+'numpy_dataset(300)-25-25-25.npy', Data_set)
        print("%s time takes in seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I want to save the list in numpy file, my problem is, with approximately 400 images (400, 2) memory gets full, my laptop has 8gb RAM, can anyone tell me what is caused this huge memory usage? is there any way to solve this?

Comment: What are the actual dimensions of your images? You seem to be reading some 25x25x25 blocks... so are these not standard images, but concatenated images to give a 3d map (using numerous CT scans)? Also ,what datatype are they?

Answer (score 1):

This will all depend on the dimensions of each of your images. Medical images are usually quite large. Below are some examples of how you can determine this and see how much memory each image (or an array thereof) is occupying in memory (RAM).

Here is an example of 400 images, each of with `shape = (400, 400, 3)`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: from sys import getsizeof
In [3]: a = np.random.rand(400, 400, 400, 3)

In [4]: getsizeof(a)
Out[4]: 1536000144

In [5]: getsizeof(a) / 10**6
Out[5]: 1536.000144               # in Mb
```

So you see it should not take more that ~ 1.6 Gb. And this is the worst case, where you have data type `np.float64`:

```
In [6]: a.shape
Out[6]: (400, 400, 400, 3)

In [7]: a.dtype
Out[7]: dtype('float64')

Make a copy of the data, this time in `np.float32` format:

In [8]: b = a.astype(np.float32)

In [9]: getsizeof(b) / 10**6
Out[9]: 768.000144                    # in Mb
```

---

I would recommend creating two numpy matrices: one for the images and one for the labels. Then save them separately too.

Using the methods above, you should be able to compute how many images you can compute in each step, then simply break down your loop into several smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

The code memory use is high because it is loading all images into memory at the same time. Change the code to loop over the images one-at-time.